# from within a static function how to place info into iVars?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

And note that I can not pass in a ViewController pointer due to this function being passed into another function.

```
static int callback(void *NotUsed, int argc, char **argv, char **azColName)
{
    NSString *str = @""; 

    int i;

    for(i=0; i<argc; i++)
    {
        printf("%s = %s\n", azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL");
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%s = %s\n", str, azColName[i], argv[i] ? argv[i] : "NULL"];
    }
    printf("\n");


    //tvDisplay is a UITextView
    [tvDisplay setText:str]; // <---- ??? how to get to an iVar
    return 0;
}
```

---

the call:

```
rc = sqlite3_exec(db, pSQL[i], callback, 0, &zErrMsg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Callback functions typically have an argument that allows you to pass along arbitrary data (it's usually a `void *` called context or something similar). You can pass in the object that you need to access when you set up the callback function, and then retrieve it within the callback function:

```
static void myCallback(int someResult, void *context) {
   SomeClass *someObject = (SomeClass *)context;
   [someObject doStuff];
}
```

In your particular case, the place for the "arbitrary data that you want to access in the callback function" is the `void *` argument right after the callback function itself that you have presently set to 0:

```
int sqlite3_exec(
  sqlite3*,                                  /* An open database */
  const char *sql,                           /* SQL to be evaluated */
  int (*callback)(void*,int,char**,char**),  /* Callback function */
  void *,                                    /* 1st argument to callback */
  char **errmsg                              /* Error msg written here */
);
```

Keep in mind that you're responsible for ensuring that any data you stick in there remains valid while the callback has not yet returned, and, if necessary, free it in the callback.